# When did 石井 四郎 (Shirō Ishii) start medical school?

Tags: world-war-two, war, japan

石井 四郎 (Shirō Ishii) was a surgeon in the Japanese Army, making the rank of General and earned the Order of the Golden Kite, Fourth Class. He committed war crimes, but made a deal with the U.S. to give what he learned for his freedom. The U.S. accepted. He died of throat cancer.

I am writing a paper about him for class, but can't seem to find anything on his early life, save for when/where he was born. The earliest thing after that is he went to Kyoto Imperial University to study medicine. Then when he was commissioned into the army in 1921.

Do we know anything of his early life apart from what I mentioned? When did he start medical school?

Comment: Ishii Shirō enrolled in the medical school of the Imperial Kyoto University in 1916, and graduated in 1920. He previously attended the Fourth High School in Kanazawa, and the Chiba Middle School before that.

Comment: I have stingy teachers about sources. You find in book, website, newspaper...?

Comment: Please keep your questions focused - when Ishii first went to uni, is a very different question from whether he continued human experimentation after WW2 (pretty sure he did not). If you want to ask about the latter, you should start a new question. Anyway, a quick google search found this [article on Ishii's early resume, along with the rest of Unit 731's members](http://war-medicine-ethics.com/Seniken/Journal/J13-2_Nishiyama1.pdf). Check page 12.

Comment: Also @Semaphore I don't read Japanese. Is there a translate?

Comment: Can't you use Google translate? I haven't seen an English source.